# How do you execute an INSERT statement using MySQL (in c++)?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

Google is failing me (or I am failing Google.)

I am simply looking for the function that executes an INSERT statement using the mysql.h library in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too familiar with using MySQL in C, but according to what I can see in the [mysql.h](http://leithal.cool-tools.co.uk/sourcedoc/mysql509/html/mysql_8h.html) file, you should call mysql_stmt_prepare to create the statement, and mysql_stmt_execute to execute said prepared statement.

Comment: For my purposes, this was the most help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [MySQL++](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/apis-cplusplus.html)?

http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/

Answer (score 0):

I've got some mysql wrapper code that you can use for reference, just look at the function called **kGUIDBRecord::Save** on the page 
http://code.google.com/p/kgui/source/browse/trunk/kguidb.cpp